# How to verify if python was compiled with Open SSL Libraries

Tags: python, openssl

## GOAL

Verify Python installation has been compiled using the OpenSSL libraries.  Connector documentation indicates this is a [requirement for SSL support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-installation.html):

> "verify that your Python installation has been compiled using the
>   OpenSSL libraries"

Update: in this case the target OS is Raspbian Jessie which has Python 2.7

## QUESTION

Is there a command line test that can be performed to confirm compilation with OpenSSL libraries?

Answer (score 8):

It will probably be sufficient to attempt to import the `ssl` module:

```
try:
    import ssl
except ImportError:
    print('No SSL')
```

On the command line:

```
$ python -c 'import ssl' >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo 'installed' || echo 'not installed'
```